# How to assign tuple to cell using iat?

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, assign, deprecation-warning

When trying to assign a tuple to a cell, I receive a deprecation warning. I'm trying to use iat as opposed to set_value or other deprecated assignment method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0]})
df.iat[0,0] = (0,[0])
```

> Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.

The issue seems linked to the tuple's embedded list. I've been unable to find a way to assign the tuple without a warning. Note the following assigns without a warning but turns the tuple into a list, not what's desired.

```
df.iat[0,0] = np.array((0,[0]),dtype=object)
```

Note that when you create a column with a tuple, `iat` will be able to assign a new tuple without a warning:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[tuple((1,[1]))]})
print(type(df.iat[0,0]),df.iat[0,0])
df.iat[0,0] = tuple((2,[2]))
print(type(df.iat[0,0]),df.iat[0,0])
```

Comment: This is actually a warning from `numpy`, I'm not sure if there is anything you can do, probably, the `pandas` maintainers will have to fix how this all works. Ultimately, trying to put `list` and `tuple` objects in numpy arrays and pandas data structures is usually not a good idea to begin with...

Comment: The ability to use lists/tuples/objects in pandas is very helpful. Can you recommend an alternate method or a guideline?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the list in the tuple. Dataframes use NumPy arrays, and NumPy arrays stores elements as blocks with a constant size. For example, `int32` arrays have elements of 32 bits, each representing an integer. In your case you're trying to add a tuple, and that has no numerical type NumPy can recognize. Therefore, it asked you to specify `dtype = object`: that just means the array will store pointers to Python objects. Since Python tuples don't have a fixed size determined by their type, you won't ever have a `dtype` where the tuple is stored directly instead of a pointer.

Comment: @BatWannaBe yeah, but even if you specify that the column has `dtype=object` the warning doesn't go away. This is occurring because of how `.iat` is being implemented.

Comment: Using pandas 1.3.2, the warning does go away, as expected. Works ok except the cell becomes a list and not a tuple.

Comment: Well it didn't become a list, it became a NumPy array. NumPy will generally recognize any nested iterables with N layers of rectangular shape as an N-D array, it's hard to get an iterable as its own element.

Comment: The only way I can really think of to get around NumPy's array construction behavior is to initialize one with the shape I want `x = np.zeros(1, dtype = object)` and then put the elements in `x[0] = (0, [0])`

Comment: Putting the tuple in x[0] still has the issue that the cell is a list/np.array and not a tuple.

Comment: Again, very important to understand, `pandas` is **not designed around the use case of putting `tuple` objects in your dataframe**. If you want to do this, then know it's going to be working against the pandas/numpy API

Comment: I can find no citation which supports your thesis "not designed around the use case of putting tuple objects in your dataframe". Clearly python objects are supported and documented in every pandas book. I agree python objects are not a native/first-class datatype. Is that what you mean?